# Different between Global Variable, StorageService and LocalSettings

Tags: c#, uwp

What is the different for LocalSetting and Global Variable? 
How to decide use of LocalSetiting or Global Variable in UWP project as both of it show the same output to me?

I am trying to store a user setting that will be use in different views. which is the recommend way to store the user setting?

Comment: Store your settings, reboot, and run the app again.  Now is there a difference in behavior?

Answer (score 1):

LocalSettings is a persistent filesystem based settings storage solution, it is basically a type of xml schema that is 'statically' accessed Through **ApplicationData** thus giving the impression it is actually something other than it is.

Global variables are your typical variables, case they are defined in a class, they will be accessible throughout that class, you get the idea.